# When a cable is suspended from two points, it hangs in the form of a catenary, the equation of the curve being given by

Tags: trigonometry

> When a cable is suspended from two points, it hangs in the form of a caternary, the equation of the curve being given by
>   $$
> s = 2a \sinh{\frac{x}{a}}\tag{1}
> $$
>   $$
> y = a\left( \cosh{\frac{x}{a}}-1 \right)\tag{2}
> $$
>   where $y$ is the sag of the cable, $x$ is the horizontal distance from the midpoint to one end of the cable, $a$ is the height of the lowest point of the cable and $s$ is the cable length.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7PcI.png)

> A heavy cable of 15 m is hanging between poles with the cable attached to each pole at the same height above ground level. 
>   At the midpoint between the poles the cable should be 5.6 m above ground level. 
>   Find
>
> - i)  the required distance between the two poles
> - ii) the minimum height of each pole.

Comment: Hi John and welcome to MathStackexchange! Questions of type "here's my homework, please solve it" are usually not very well received here, unless you tell what you have tried so far. So please share your own attempts.

Comment: See [How To Ask A Homework Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/265466).

Comment: Hey guys, look at the photo he has posted. If that is genuine, he does not look like a homework-leech. Anyway, I am going to post an answer to his question.

Comment: @John Aird Your text states $s$ as the cable length, but your diagram depicts $s$ as the half-length of the cable. Which one is correct?

Comment: I have taken this as s is 7.5m as the rope is 15m and its half.

Comment: @YNK - I've looked at the photo, and it looks exactly like a homework question. John - Matti P is correct. Please add your thoughts about the problem and indicate where you are having trouble. We want to help you learn the subject - not avoid learning it by doing your work for you.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair Which photo did you look at? The photo that shows his face or his sketch of the caternary?. In my earlier comment, I meant the former. He looks a bit too old to be a student doing homework, no offence John.

Comment: Yes I am in my 40’s I work so no offence taken YNK. the example is a old question I found online. I was just wanting to learn caternary.  I was using you tube  exemples but they gave the pole length couldn’t  find the right equations to solve this with combination of figures given. From your picture from A to C that would be 15m but s in mine was half the rope which is 7.5. But thank you for taking the time to helping me understand appreciated.

Comment: p=√(7.5^2 +5.6^2)=9.360021367m which I got the same result

Comment: @John Aird Nice to hear from you. Thanks for your comment. In future, if you have this type of practice-oriented problems, you can post them on $\bf{\rm{Engineering\space StackExchange}}$ as well.

Comment: thanks it the first time I have used one I will do appreciated
p=√(7.5^2 +5.6^2)=9.360021367m 
which I got the same result
x=aln((s+p)/a)   x=5.6ln((7.5+9.36)/5.6)=6.172m

Comment: @John Aird .It is good to see that you have cracked the problem yourself. Kudos to you!.

Comment: The way you have defined your terms, "$y$ is the sag of the cable, $x$ is the horizontal distance from the midpoint to one end of the cable, $a$ is the height of the lowest point of the cable and $s$ is the cable length," neither equations $(1)$ nor $(2)$ is an equation of a curve. Each equation simply gives a relation among the four discrete named quantities $y,x,a,s$ and says nothing about what happens at any point of the cable other than the midpoint or the ends. Equation $(2)$, however, *could have been* the equation of a catenary curve if you defined $x$ and $y$ differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replying to my comment. Unfortunately, it did not help me to clear my doubts. Therefore, I will use the standard method of solving your problem assuming what you have mentioned in your text is correct. 
That also means I am ignoring your sketch, which I think is wrong, because it dose not agree with the first equation. Therefore, I am attaching my own sketch for you to follow and understand the text given below.

[image: Catenary]

The length of the cable $s$ is equal to $\bf{15}$ m. Since the height of the lowest point of the cable is $\bf{5.6}$ m, $a=5.6$. According to the diagram, $x=FE$. From (1), we have,
$$s=2a\sinh\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) \space \to\space 15=2\times5.6\times\sinh\left(\frac{FE}{5.6}\right).$$
$$\therefore FE=5.6\times \sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{15}{2\times 5.6}\right)\approx6.1722\space \rm{m}$$
Now we use (2) to calculate the sag $y$, which is denoted by $DB$.
$$y=a\left(\cosh\left(\frac{FE}{a}\right)-1\right)\space\to\space DB=5.6\times\left(\cosh\left(\frac{6.1722}{5.6}\right)-1\right)=3.76\space\rm{m}$$
The distance between the two poles is $FG$ and it is equal to $2x$, i.e. 
$$FG=2\times FE=2\times 6.1722=12.3444\space \rm{m}.$$
The minimum height of each pole is $DE$ and is given by $\left(a+y\right)$, i.e.
$$AF=CG=DE=DB+a=3.76+5.6=9.36\space \rm{m}.$$

$\color{red} {\underline{Note}:}$
Because I could not agree with you on certain parts of your problem description, I cannot take responsibility for the values I gave above as answers to your question. Therefore, you use them at your own risk. At the same time, feel free to comment on my answer.